# Traveling to Nassau Bahamas is more safer compared to Nicholls town ? is safe to visit alone or need a guide? The beaches are secure?

Tags: cruising, bahamas

Traveling to Nassau Bahamas is more safer compared to  Nicholls town ?

is safe to visit alone or need a guide?
The beaches are secure?

Comment: no-one can decide for you whether something is safe enough. You can ask how the crime rate on Nassau beaches compares to specific other places you're familiar with, or something else specific that has a single correct answer. Then make your own decisions based on the facts you've learned.

Comment: Many governments publish travel advice for their citizens: for example, the British government advice for visitors to the Bahamas is [here](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/bahamas). I believe the US and Australia also publish such advice, which you can find, and use to come to your own conclusions.

Comment: I think a general answer could be given to this question without going all "opinion-based". It should be reopened.

Comment: Edited the question. Tank you!